# GSA: How to show results that don't have any documents/attachments in them

Tags: google-search-appliance

In my GSA frontend I have is a option that when clicked should show only results which dont have any files(pdf or any)

so what i need is way to modify my url so that i get only results with no files. **What should be the url parameter?**

Also any reference if I can do it through Google Frontend

Comment: Are you looking to show results that have no content, just metadata in the index?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by show results that don't have any file?  Do you mean don't show web pages that have embedded PDF documents or don't show PDF results at all?

As far as the GSA is concerned a PDF document is the same as an HTML document and there is no "knowledge" the GSA has if there is an embedded attachment.

If you are looking to exclude PDF, Office files, etc, then you could create a different collection that excludes those or you could use a different "client" that uses the "remove URLs" to exclude the URL patterns you don't want.

Comment: I want don't show PDF results at all. Is there any url parameter for doing this. For example there is a url parameter "as_filetype=pdf" which will show results that have pdf files. I want something like "as_filetype=none"

Comment: Easiest way to do this, really, is to build a collection, that excludes all of these.  Then call that collection.  But you could also try &as_filetype=pdf,ppt,pptx,doc,docx,xls,xlsx&as_dt=e

Comment: i would prefer &as_filetype. But is &as_filetype=pdf,ppt,pptx,doc,docx correct or it should be &as_filetype=pdf|ppt$|doc$&as_ft=e. So basically now I have 3 doubts 1. how to separate multiple file types using , or | 2. can i use ppt$ to exclude ppt and pptx and 3. you have written &as_dt=e. Shouldnt it be &as_ft=e